# Converting Timestamp to actual Date in SQL

Tags: sql

i am trying to convert timestamps such as

```
0x0000000000C7442B
0x0000000000C7442C
0x0000000000C7442D
0x0000000000C7442E
0x0000000000C7442F
0x0000000000C74430
```

in SQL to date. 
Anyone with any idea on how to achieve it?

Here is my Query

```
select Fixed_assets.timestamp as Date,Fixed_assets.Description,No_ as [Tag Number],Fa_Ledger.Amount as Cost, Fixed_assets.[Location Code], [Useful Life], [Depreciation Rate]
from Fixed_assets 
inner join Fa_Ledger on Fixed_assets.No_ = Fa_Ledger.[FA No_]
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (ANSI SQL has no such functionality.)

Answer (score 4):

[You can't.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.130).aspx)

> The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
> preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime
> data type.
>
> rowversion is the synonym for the timestamp data type and is subject
> to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use
> rowversion instead of timestamp wherever possible.
>
> The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is different from the timestamp
> data type defined in the ISO standard.
>
> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a
> future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in
> new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently
> use this feature.

I assumed SQL Server.